# Unable to load tiles with basic Spring 3.0 MVC example

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC from [Spring In Action 3rd Edition](http://www.manning.com/walls4/)

As per examples given in that book, I am implementing the Spitter application using Spring 3.0 MVC and Tiles-2 using Eclipse as IDE and deploying the application on tomcat 6.0 server.

When I try to access the pages of my application using URL(`http://localhost:8081/SpringInAction3/spitter/spittles?spitter=test`), I am just getting an error saying:

`Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'spittle' available as request attribute`

Here is my tiles configuration file view.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
"http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="top"
            value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/spittleForm.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="side"
            value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/signinsignup.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="home" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="spittles/list" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/spittles/list.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Spring configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.habuma.spitter"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/views.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Sevlet mapping in web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

main_template.jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Spitter</title>
    <link href="<s:url value="/resources" />/css/spitter.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" 
          type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <a href="<s:url value="/home" />"><img 
          src="<s:url value="/resources" />/images/spitter_logo_50.png" 
          border="0"/></a>
      <div id="top">
        <t:insertAttribute name="top" /> <!--<co id="co_tile_top" />-->
      </div>
      <div id="side">
        <t:insertAttribute name="side" /> <!--<co id="co_tile_side" />-->
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <t:insertAttribute name="content" /> <!--<co id="co_tile_content" />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spitter")
public class SpitterController {
    private final SpitterService spitterService;

    @Inject
    public SpitterController(SpitterService spitterService) {
        this.spitterService = spitterService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/spittles", method = GET)
    public String listSpittlesForSpitter(
            @RequestParam("spitter") String username, Model model) {
        Spitter spitter = spitterService.getSpitter(username);
        model.addAttribute(spitter);
        model.addAttribute(spitterService.getSpittlesForSpitter(username));
        return "spittles/list";
    }
}
```

My list.jsp is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<div>
    <h2>Spittles for ${spitter.username}</h2>
    <table cellspacing="15">
        <c:forEach items="${spittleList}" var="spittle">
            <tr>
                <td><img
                    src="<s:url value= "/resources/images/spitter_avatar.png"/>"
                    width="48" height="48"/></td>
                <td><a
                    href="<s:url value= "/spitters/${spittle.spitter.username}"/>">
                    ${spittle.spitter.username}</a> <c:out
                        value="${spittle.text}" /><br /> <c:out value="${spittle.when}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

Please let me know where I made mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in one of your JSPs (possibly `spittleForm.jsp` not shown) is trying to bind to a model object called `spittle`. But this model object is not available when a request to `/spittles` is made.

You're probably best to ensure that the controller mapping for `/spittles` adds the necessary model object to satisfy the form binding.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/spittles", method = GET)
public String listSpittlesForSpitter(
        @RequestParam("spitter") String username, Model model) {
    Spitter spitter = spitterService.getSpitter(username);
    model.addAttribute(spitter);
    model.addAttribute(spitterService.getSpittlesForSpitter(username));

    model.addAttribute("spittle", new Spittle()); // Add an empty model 

    return "spittles/list";
}
```

Comment: Yes, the other JSP files are using that model object. I am surprised to see why the book has not mentioned about the possibility of this issue. Thanks a lot @Will